# How can I download and install refind bootloader (0.7.7.1)?

Tags: software-installation

I've seen an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329030/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-gt60) on installing Ubuntu on `MSI-GT60` laptop on this site. It suggests that I should install `rEFInd bootloader` but I can't find it anywhere.

How can I install this?

Answer (score 0):

Download rEFInd Boot Manager for Ubuntu from its page [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) or the current version `0.7.8` from  [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.7.8/refind_0.7.8-1_amd64.deb/download).

Since it is `.deb` file installation is as easy as double clicking the `.deb` file which will open the installer to install it.

or from the terminal you can do

```
dpkg -i name_of_file_you_downloaded.deb
```

to install it.

Comment: The Sourceforge link is fine today, but in the future it will point to an old version. I recommend linking to the main rEFInd page at http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ or its download page at http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html. A link to the Sourceforge download page at https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/?source=navbar will also work, but the user will then need to select the version to be downloaded (that's just one more click, but some people seem to be puzzled by being dropped in the middle of a directory tree).

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for refind are here:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/
http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/#troubleshooting